# How much memory will allocated for a mysql view

Tags: mysql

How much memory will allocated for a mysql view,if not how it works,if allocated how much will be allocated.

Comment: Somewhere between x and y bytes.

Comment: As much as it needs, and no more? That'd be my guess, which is why it's a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When views use the [TEMPTABLE algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html), the memory allocated will be relative to the size of the temp table, which depends on the number of rows and lengths of columns.

I don't know any more specific answer than that.